# Should I convert timezones when moving data to a report server/data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, replication, ssis, data-warehouse, timezone

I'm writing an SSIS Package to take data from a production DB to a reports server/data warehouse. The other databases on my reports server are all in Mountain Time but this DB is in UTC should I convert the data as I'm importing it with SSIS, or should I leave the data as is and just keep track of what time zone the server data is in and deal with it in my queries? Is there a reason not to convert the data as I copy it over?

Comment: Time Zone conversion can be tricky if not handled properly. I normally prefer to use @AaronBertrand 's method of creating a calendar table. He has written a [3 part series on mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3175/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server--part-3/) which will give you a good start.

Comment: Is there location data associated with the times? e.g. plant, store, etc.?

Comment: @Dave There is not any location data associated, we only have one location and all reporting should be done in Mountain time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason to *not* convert the timezone, and to keep the times in UTC. Times in UTC can be converted on-the-fly to any given timezone (and timezone's do occasionally shift, and Daylight Savings rules shift even more often). UTC is always accurate, whereas timezones and regions that allow for Daylight Savings Time have overlaps in the "fall-back" period when you repeat a particular hour. Save yourself a lot of pain down the road and keep the data in the current, more accurate format.

For the purposes of efficient searching, either convert incoming time ranges to UTC first, or, create a non-persisted computed column that represents Mountain Time (be sure to look up the historical rules governing start/end dates for DST) and create a NonClustered Index on that computed column.

Answer (score 0):

Srutzky has offered the more resilient solution, which you should consider, but from the description of a single location and single reporting time zone I'd suggest the most easily implemented and maintained solution is to simply convert to MTN during ETL (and/or change that server's settings). Don't build a cruise ship when all you need is a row boat.

However... I'd ask a business user to confirm your approach. They might not tell you about that secret new C-level plan for an office in Naples, but they can tell you UTC is necessary.

*Also* - only convert to MTN if that makes sense... if you have an e-commerce site and users are making purchases at --PM EST and you change that to --PM MTN you're horribly corrupting your data and rendering it useless for a good deal of analysis.

Comment: Re: "Don't build a cruise ship when all you need is a row boat" I generally agree with this sentiment, but in this case, I'm not sure I would consider _not_ losing accuracy as being over-engineering ;-).